# Error while building lua 5.4.3 with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lua

What I did:

1. Download [lua-5.4.3.tar.gz](https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.4.3.tar.gz)
2. Create 3 projects in Visual Studio

   - library (dll)

     Add lapi.c lcode.c lctype.c ldebug.c ldo.c ldump.c lfunc.c lgc.c llex.c lmem.c lobject.c lopcodes.c lparser.c lstate.c lstring.c ltable.c ltm.c lundump.c lvm.c lzio.c lauxlib.c lbaselib.c lcorolib.c ldblib.c liolib.c lmathlib.c loadlib.c loslib.c lstrlib.c ltablib.c lutf8lib.c linit.c

     Add LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL flag
   - interpreter (exe)

     Add lua.c

     Add library dependency
   - compiler (exe)

     Add luac.c

     Add library dependency
3. Build the solution

library and interpreter were built successfully, but I got 2 errors for the compiler project.

> 1>luac.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaG_getfuncline referenced in function _PrintCode

> 1>luac.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaU_dump referenced in function _pmain

How to fix them?

Comment: You need to define `LUA_CORE` when creating your dll https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/luaconf.h.html#LUA_DIRSEP

Comment: Thanks for reply, but `LUA_CORE` is defined at the begining of `luac.c`

Comment: Did you add `LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL` to your compiler and interpreter builds?

Comment: I've tried, but the error remains.

Comment: Finally I choose to add dllexport to these 2 functions.

Comment: luac is meant to be built statically.

Comment: @lhf Thanks, that's a useful information.